# .NET MongoDB: Deserialize BsonDocument from BsonType Array

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bson

I look for the answer but nothing helps, so I post the question again, hope someone could help me out.
Let's say I have a simple JSON string like this:

```
 [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "B"
      }
 ]
```

And here is my code to parse that JSON into BsonDocument

```
        using (var jsonreader = new JsonReader(json_data))
        {
            var context = BsonDeserializationContext.CreateRoot(jsonreader);
            //Bson Array, how to deserialize???
            var document = collection.DocumentSerializer.Deserialize(context);
            collection.InsertOne(document);
        }
```

It will return the error "System.FormatException: 'Cannot deserialize a 'BsonDocument' from BsonType 'Array'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to directly convert Json to BsonDocument you should do it as following:

```
BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(json_data.toString());
```

You might want to share more of your code to give clearer picture of what are you trying to do. Anyway, I hope this sorts your issue.